spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate causes validation errors after upgrading of Spring Boot 2.7 to 3.3
I have a legacy app running Spring Boot 2.7.x with Hibernate 5.6. This app imports another project that runs on same Spring Boot version and pretty much only contains DB entity classes. In my application.properties file of the legacy app, I set
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate

The app so far started without problems.
Then I updated the legacy app to Spring Boot 3.3.2, which comes with Hibernate 6.5. Because Spring Boot 3 comes with the jakarta.persistence namespace, I also had to update the namespace (and also Spring Boot to 3.3.2) in the project that contains the Entity classes. After starting the legacy app, again, I started receiving lots of validation errors like that, especially for fields that use the Date type in my entities:

Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column
[value_date] in table [movements]; found [date (Types#DATE)],
but expecting [datetime(6) (Types#TIMESTAMP)]

MySQL DB type here is set to date and the entity is mapped as java.util.Date type
But also for some Integer fields:

Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [field_id] in
table [field_lookup]; found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting
[tinyint (Types#TINYINT)]

MySQL DB type here is set to int(11) and the entity is mapped as follows:
@Column(name = "field_id")
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private Field field;

with Field being an enum:
public enum Field {
    MT_MESSAGE_FUNCTION, BUY_SELL_INDICATOR, LINK_REFERENCE, MT_MESSAGE_BODY
}

This is the pom.xml of my legacy app:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>myEntityPackage</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
            <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build> omitted for brevity
    </build>
</project>

And the pom.xml of my entity package:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>myEntityPackage</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </parent>

    <name>myEntityPackage</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

The application.properties file:
spring.application.name=myApp
spring.datasource.url = xxx
spring.datasource.username = xxx
spring.datasource.password = xxx

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

My question: because I did not receive these kinds of errors with the old Spring 2.7 and Hibernate 5.6, I would like to understand why these errors are showing up now after the update. Is it caused by Spring Boot 3, or by Hibernate? What's the root cause?

please show  your pom.xml.

Have added both poms.

spring boot 3 require Java 17+,  please goto https://start.spring.io/ , use it to create your project.

I am building and running with Java 21, the old version tag in the pom is just not updated yet, but it's also not used in any maven build configuration. So that should not be causing the issues.

please show your application.properties.

I think the log is very clear. You got conflict in your type. Nowadays I always try to use LocalDateTime or LocalDate with SPpringboot, that work well with Time and Date also
